# Java repainting the gui

Tags: java, paint, frame-rate

in my 2D-game i have the main class and the gameWindow class, in the main class i have an update method which updates 60 per second and i want to call the repaint method from the gameWindow class and call it in the main class when update

**Main Class:**

```
private static final int FPS = 60;

public static void main(String[] args){

    new Main().startGame();

    gameWindow g = new gameWindow();
    g.setSize(900, 700);
    g.setVisible(true);
    g.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    g.setResizable(true);
}

/**
 * they main method that will run the gameWindow and also runs on the FPS and to maintain the same FPS
 */
private void startGame() {

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){

            updateGame();
        }

    },0, 1000 / FPS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

/**
 * what should be include when the game is updated by the FPS method
 */
public void updateGame() {

    //here where i wanna call the repaint method
    repaint();
}
```

there is nothing much in the gameWindow Class all what i want is to call repaint method in the gameUpdate()

Comment: Couldn't you just change `repaint();` to `this.repaint();` ?

Comment: @liquidsystem - Pretty sure `repaint()` and `this.repaint()` are equivalent unless the method is hidden by a user defined `repaint()` method

Comment: What `repaint` does is schedule a paint request. You shouldn't rely on the normal window painting for your application, checkout [a BufferStrategy tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) - your main render loop should look similar to the example in the link.

Comment: @cricket_007 - Sorry I've only done a small amount of GUI.
Also, at Heroxlegend, are you wanting to repaint all of the items or just the game itself? I know when I made one for my class we had to repaint all of the objects over the frame itself.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill, but my strategy for implementing a redrawable component with FPS is four steps with OOP patterns.

Note the first two steps can work with any object, not just GUI components.

An interface for delegating a manual refresh

```
public interface IRefreshable {
    public void refresh();
}
```

A Thread object that takes in an `IRefreshable` implementation and the FPS

```
public class Repainter extends Thread {
    private int fps;
    private final IRefreshable comp;

    public Repainter(IRefreshable comp, int fps) {
        this.comp = comp;
        this.fps = fps;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000 / this.fps);
                this.comp.refresh();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setFPS(int fps) {
        this.fps = fps;
    }
}
```

An abstract `JComponent` that maintains the FPS and the thread that redraws the component

```
public abstract class RepaintableComponent extends JComponent implements IRefreshable {

    private static int FPS = 60;
    protected Repainter repainterThread;

    public RepaintableComponent(boolean continuousRedraw) {
        if (continuousRedraw) {
            repaintAtFPS(FPS);
        }
    }

    public RepaintableComponent() {
        this(true);
    }

    protected void repaintAtFPS(int fps) {
        if (this.repainterThread == null) {
            this.repainterThread = new Repainter(this, fps);
            this.repainterThread.start();
        } else {
            this.repainterThread.setFPS(fps);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void refresh() {
        repaint();
        revalidate();
    }
}
```

And finally, an (untested) concrete implementation of the `RepaintableComponent`. Any following calls to `setColor` on this Panel should update its background color.

```
public class ColoredPanel extends RepaintableComponent {
    private Color bg;

    public ColoredPanel(Color c) {
        super();
        this.bg = c;
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        setLayout(layout);
    }

    public void setColor(Color c) {
        this.bg = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(bg);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```